# Reading the value of a byte in Racket

Tags: byte, marshalling, racket

In my program I have to communicate over TCP/IP.
To do so I have to marshall the data I want to send.
Sometimes I want to send an integer, this fits perfectly in one byte.

In Racket an integer (0 <= number < 256) is considered to be a byte.
So for example I send :

```
(write 15 outputPort)
(flush-output outputPort)
```

At the other end, the receiver has to unmarshall the received data.
So I do :

```
(define (loop)
    (if (byte-ready? inputPort)
        (display (read-byte inputPort))
        (loop)))
```

I would suppose it to display 15 (as all numbers between 0 and 255 can fit in one byte) but instead it displays 49 which is the ASCII value of "1".
And if I loop one more I will receive 53 as second value which is the ASCII value of "5".

So is there a manner to make a byte from a value between 0 and 255 without transforming each digit of the number to an ASCII value because that causes to send N bytes were N is the number of digits in the number.

If it isn't possible, what's the advantage of bytes in Racket?
As I could simply send my number as a string :

```
(write (number->string 15) outputPort)
(flush-output outputPort)
```

And then unmarshall it by reading a string and then convert in the other way :

```
(string->number (read-string length inputPort))
```

But I wanted to use bytes in order to avoid sending strings (because operations on strings are costly) so I could send one byte for a number between 0 and 255 instead of possibly 3 bytes (when the number contains 3 digits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`write-byte`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Output.html?q=write-byte#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._write-byte%29%29), not `write`:

```
-> (write-byte 61)
=
-> (write 61)
61
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `write-byte` instead of `write` it will actually send the byte value instead of the serialized representation of the value.

Similarly, you can use `write-bytes` to write a bytestring out byte-by-byte.